# Django upload model - user permissions

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-authentication, django-permissions

I am creating a file upload page which has a file upload model:

**models.py**

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, validators=[validate_file_extension])
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('can_upload_x', 'Can Upload X'),
            ('can_upload_y', 'Can Upload Y'),
            ('can_upload_z', 'Can Upload Z'),
        )
```

**forms.py**

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Upload
    fields = ['file']
```

**html**

```
{% if perms.app.can_upload_x %}

<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type='hidden' name='action' value='x'>
    {% csrf_token %} {{form_x}}
<input type="submit" value="Upload" id="weights_btn" name="weights_btn" 
class="btn btn-default btn-file"/>
</form>
{%endif%}

#etc for X, Y, Z, ....
```

So the end goal is for the users assigned to have certain permissions from the admin like 'can_upload_x' will only be able to see the form for X etc ( I make different forms save to different locations with handle_uploaded_file in the views).

What am I doing wrong? does not seem to work. It did, however work when I had a model for each form but it is unfeasible for my project since I might have to have a whole lot of different forms.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if perms.app_label.can_do_something %}
    <form here>
{% endif %}
```

is your `app_label` named by `app`?

Comment: well it's called 'upload_auth' I just tried to make example as generic as possible.

Comment: try `{% if perms.upload_auth.can_upload_x %}`